# Laravel memcached - If one of the servers goes down, memcached doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

Laravel Version
10.4.1

PHP Version
8.2.1

I have 2 memcached servers configured. As it currently works, if one of the servers goes down, memcached doesn't work.
The correct solution would be if one server stops, the other one is still working.
This is unfortunately not the case at the moment.
Could you confirm if this is a problem or am I mistake something?

Steps To Reproduce
File: src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php

Current source:

```
public function connect(array $servers, $connectionId = null, array $options = [], array $credentials = [])
{
    $memcached = $this->getMemcached(
        $connectionId, $credentials, $options
    );

    if (! $memcached->getServerList()) {
        // For each server in the array, we'll just extract the configuration and add
        // the server to the Memcached connection. Once we have added all of these
        // servers we'll verify the connection is successful and return it back.
        foreach ($servers as $server) {
            $memcached->addServer(
                $server['host'], $server['port'], $server['weight']
            );
        }
    }

    return $memcached;
}
```